# Converting txt file into a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json

I am trying to convert a file with string dictionaries into a list of dictionaries. The file can be found here: https://github.com/szczor/sharing/blob/master/data.txt . Here is how I try it:

```
lista = []
with open(os.path.join(path_to_data, 'data.txt')) as filehandle:
    for line in filehandle:
        # remove linebreak which is the last character of the string
        currentPlace = line[:-1]

        # add item to the list
        lista.append(currentPlace)
```

So I have a list, now with elements which are string.

```
print(type(lista[0]))
```

Now trying to convert those strings to dictionaries with

```
lista = [json.loads(str(string.replace('\'','\"'))) for string in lista]
```

But get an error

```
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I tried the same method with manually created list and everything worked, but have no idea why it does not work with my txt file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` for this:

```
import ast
with open(os.path.join(path_to_data, 'data.txt')) as fp:

    lines = fp.readlines()


# if there are irregularities, use a try/except to pass these (note, you may wish to use a logger in practice)    
output = []
for line in lines:
    try:
        output.append(ast.literal_eval(line))
    except ValueError:
        print("malformed string; skipping this line")
    except SyntaxError:
        print("looks like some encoding errors with this file...")
```

output:

```
[{'Lines': '130',
  'Lon': 21.0082356,
  'VehicleNumber': '1000',
  'Time': '2020-12-23 14:19:31',
  'Lat': 52.207217,
  'Brigade': '2'},
 {'Lines': '213',
  'Lon': 21.1013111,
  'VehicleNumber': '1001',
  'Time': '2020-12-23 15:40:37',
  'Lat': 52.2230756,
  'Brigade': '2'},
 {'Lines': '130',
  'Lon': 21.003573,
  'VehicleNumber': '1002',
  'Time': '2020-12-23 15:40:39',
  'Lat': 52.2060591,
  'Brigade': '1'},
 {'Lines': '311',
  'Lon': 21.0807406,
  'VehicleNumber': '1003',
  'Time': '2020-12-23 15:40:35',
  'Lat': 52.2414656,
  'Brigade': '2'},
 {'Lines': '213',
  'Lon': 21.1746171,
  'VehicleNumber': '1004',
  'Time': '2020-12-23 15:40:24',
  'Lat': 52.186474,
  'Brigade': '3'},...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, did you use it on my file? I am getting an error: 'ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x000001E4278689A0>'

Comment: hi @wychen.  Part of it.  I can reproduce the error, debugging now

Comment: at line 23934 you have some funny text.  you can wrap in a try except to avoid this, I'll update the answer

Comment: Thank you @anon01, I was downloading via API and something must have gone wrong at some point, hence this weird text which in polish says that something went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

i could not comment to your question due to some privileges,
try

```
for line in filehandle.readlines(): #instead of just filehandle
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, but get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This oughta do the trick. `ast.literal_eval()` should be able to parse dict strings like those in the data file:

```
import ast


with open(os.path.join(path_to_data, 'data.txt')) as filehandle:
    lista = [
        ast.literal_eval(line.strip())
        for line
        in filehandle
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am getting a ValueError: "ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x00000210785710A0>"

Answer (score 0):

This is how i would approach:

```
   f = open("data.txt", "r")
   my_list = []

   for x in f: #read the sheet line by line
      dict_x = eval(x) #convert each line to dict
      my_list.append(dict_x)

   f.close()
```

Alternatively, eval() can also be substituted by dict()